# Rails: content_for not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-for

Here is my helper method:

```
  def title(page_title = "RecruitTalk | Tell Your Story")
    page_title = "#{current_user.try(:name) || current_user.try(:email)} | RecruitTalk" if user_signed_in? && current_user.athlete?
    content_for(:title) { page_title }
  end
```

Here is how I am calling it in my layout file:

```
<title><%= yield(:title) %></title>
```

Here is my how I am setting it in a view

```
<% title "Account Features" %>
```

When I refresh the page, no page title renders... not sure what I am doing wrong here

Comment: Any output from the server log? Actually I dont get the use of your helper method..

Comment: Nothing from the server log... the method is to help with setting the page title that isn't static

Comment: ``title(page_title = "RecruitTalk | Tell Your Story")`` This is whats grinding me... just try ``title(page_title)``

Comment: Where are you calling the title helper from? A view template or a partial?

Comment: @diego.greyrobot - A partial

Comment: puh... somehow its like http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/then-a-miracle-occurs-cartoon.png

Comment: Can you confirm the values of `user_signed_in?` and `current_user.athlete?`

Comment: what if you use instead of `title`, `content_for` directly?, just to test.